# Spring JPA: Change attribute of instance that is simultaniously being modified in scheduled task

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, persistence

I'm running a scheduled task in my Spring application that runs a job. The job itself is fetched at the beginning of the task. After that a loop takes place that modifies the job in each iteration (++ a counter). After the loop I merge my instance using the entity manager. It works fairly well, but I'm facing an issue trying to modify the instance from another place. Since the instance has a 'paused' flag, I'm trying to set it. But whenever I do it's quickly reset again, due to the scheduled task unsetting it again (as far as I can tell).

Here's some code:

```
// This method is called using the @Scheduled annotation to be looping
// constantly with one second delay between invocations.
@Transactional
public void performActions() {
    Job job = jobRepository.findFirstByPausedAtIsNull();
    // Skip if no unpaused job exists
    if(job == null) return;
    // Iterate through batch of job actions
    for(Action action : job.nextActions()) {
        action.perform();
        job.increaseActionsPerformedCount();
        // Merge the action into the persistence context
        entityManager.merge(action);
    }
    // Merge the job into the persistence context
    entityManager.merge(job);
}
```

Now I'm trying to be able to pause the job at any time from the outside. I use a controller endpoint to call a pause method on the jobService. This method looks like this:

```
public Job pause(long id) throws JobNotFoundException, JobStatusException {
    Job job = this.show(id);
    if(job.getPausedAt() != null) throw new JobStatusException("The job is already paused");
    job.pause(); // This sets the flag on the instance, same as job.setPausedAt(new Date())
    return jobRepository.save(campaign); // Uses CrudRepository
}
```

Now calling the method works fine and it actually returns the Job with `pausedAt` set. But the value is reset quickly after.

I've tried just straight up fetching a fresh instance from the database at the end of `performAction` and setting the modified instance `pausedAt` to the freshly fetched one's value.

Any idea how this could be achieved properly?

Comment: I will try to centralize the "data" logic inside a @Transactional method to be called from scheduled task and others. Another thing to consider is the JPA cache, maybe flushing EntityManager afer the merge/save would help.

Comment: Flushing didn't change anything I'm afraid. I also can't put the pausing logic inside the task since I won't be able to trigger it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand , You need to stop the job when the pause flag is set ... you can achieve this by applying optimistic lock ... add a `@Version` field to `Job` .... apply `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC` to the job that you retrieved in `performAction()` -either by adding it to the `find()` method or call a `refresh()` after retrieval -the first is better- ..... now if the other endpoint changes the pause flag the version field will be incremented and you will get `OptimisticLockException` at persisting .... this has some implications :

1- whatever state changes in the `Job` , the same behavior will happen (not only the pause field)

2- You will need to handle the Exception from inside the persistence context (i.e. inside `performActions()`) because after returning it might be mapped to any other exception type ... this is the idea I have now, may be there is something better that gives you more control (track only the `pause` attribute)

Comment: Yeah this really isn't ideal since the action has a few other values that change and it would be annoying to lock it with every change. i really just want to be sure that pause will actually be persisted.